# SQL Oracle query and php

Tags: php, sql, oracle

I have an issue that I can't solve. The query below prints 4 results: pCO2, Hemoglobina, pO2 and LEUCÓCITOS. I tried this in SQL Developer and it works fine. The thing is when I try to print it in my php page it is only printing the first 3 results and missing LEUCÓCITOS. I did some debugging and I came to the conclusion it was because of the accent. I tried to remove it but it still doesn't print it. 
Hope someone can help me, thanks in advance!

```
$query3 = "SELECT DISTINCT A.NPROCESSO,  A.EPISODIO, TO_CHAR(DATAVALIDACAO,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:mi:ss') AS DATAV, EXAME as EXAME, RESULTADO 
     FROM PATIENT_TIMELINE_PID A, UCI_INTERNADOS_ANALISES2S B
     WHERE NPROCESSO = 1647306 AND A.EPISODIO = B.EPISODIO AND (EXAME) IN ('pCO2','Hemoglobina','pO2', 'LEUCÓCITOS')  AND  TO_CHAR(DATAVALIDACAO,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') IN
          (SELECT DISTINCT MIN(TO_CHAR(DATAVALIDACAO,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'))
          FROM UCI_INTERNADOS_ANALISES2S H
          where B.EXAME = H.EXAME
          GROUP BY NPROCESSO, TO_CHAR(DATAVALIDACAO,'YYYYMMDDHH24'))
          ORDER BY  NPROCESSO, DATAV ASC";

$result3 = oci_parse($connect, $query3);
oci_execute($result3);

while($res3 = oci_fetch_array($result3)) {
 echo $res3["EXAME"]."<br>"; 
}
```

Comment: Did you try this way: `(EXAME IN ('pCO2','Hemoglobina','pO2') OR EXAME LIKE 'LEUC_CITOS' )`?

Comment: It worked! Thanks very much! Can you explain what is the underscore doing to make it work?

Comment: I'm not so sure to give full answer - but there must be some codepage settings issue between PHP and Oracle - database "sees" other character than `Ó` when you send it from code.

Comment: Well thanks anyway, it was really weird because it never happened to me before.

Comment: @Zalif, the underscore in a LIKE condition matches any one character. So LEUC_CITOS will match LEUCÓCITOS, LEUCaCITOS, LEUCCITOS, etc. It's not safe to use if you have similar values in your database.

Comment: I agree with @MarkLeiber. `like LEUC_CITOS` is workaround, safe way is to match charsets.